# Coloring in Combinatorial Design Generalizing Latin Square

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-colorings, matrix-theory, combinatorial-designs, latin-square

I have a question about a combinatorial design very similar to a Latin Square, which is arising out of an open problem in graph theory.  The design is an $n \times n$ matrix whose entries we want to assign colors from $\lbrace 1, 2, \dots, n \rbrace$.  A (symmetric) Latin Square is subject to the following constraints:

1) The matrix should be symmetric.

2) No row or column contains the same color more than once.

In my problem, we will want a symmetric $n \times n$ matrix, but we will allow some of the matrix entries to be identified into symmetric blocks.  In other words, suppose there is an equivalence relation $\mathcal{A}$ on the coordinates $(a_{i,j})$ which satisfies the property that if $A \in \mathcal{A}$ and $a_{i,j} \in A$, then $a_{j,i} \in A$.  The problem I am curious about is, if given an $n$ and an arbitrary such $\mathcal{A}$, is there an $n \times n$ matrix satisfying the following constraints:

1) The matrix is symmetric.

2) If $a, b \in A$ for some $A \in \mathcal{A}$, then the entries are assigned the same color, and

3) If two coordinates $a, b$ are in the same row or column as one another and they are the same color, then there is an $A \in \mathcal{A}$ such that $a, b \in A$.

In other words, it's a symmetric Latin Square 'up to equivalence by $\mathcal{A}$.'

Have these objects been studied before (with or without the symmetry condition), or are there any equivalent formulations?  I expect that it *is* possible to construct such a design.  I can only prove it in very special cases, though (e.g. where each row or column only 'intersects' at most one non-trivial equivalence class).

Comment: I would expect this is a fundamental sort of question in matroid theory, but I barely even know the definition of a matroid.  If someone has a matroid expert friend...

Comment: So you might want to replace the tag  [matrix-theory] by [matroid-theory]. 

Comment: Sincerely, I do not feel this being matroid-related, of course I may be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Hope I didn't misunderstand the question, but isn't this a counterexample (different letters correspond to different equivalence classes):

```
AAB
ACD
BDC
```

Each pair of classes have representatives in a common row/column, hence at least four colours are needed.

Comment: Maybe it's me who got a misunderstanding of the question, but what's wrong with using four colors?

Comment: Yes, it's a counterexample.  But don't worry, my actual problem is still open.  There are some extra niceties in my situation, which I'm going to rewrite into the OP.  Check back in a bit.  Honestly I totally forgot about this post haha

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, these are symmetric *frequency squares*.  Quoting from a random reference on the topic:

> An $F(n;\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_m)$ frequency square is an $n \times n$ array consisting of the numbers $1,2,\ldots,m$ with the property that for each $i = 1,\ldots,m$, the number $i$ occurs exactly $\lambda_i$ times in each row and in each column.
>   <sub>Dénes and Mullen, [Enumeration formulas for latin and frequency squares](https://doi.org/10.1016/0012-365X(93)90152-J), Disc. Math., 1993</sub>

Some Latin squares have the property that they're symbol-isotopic to their transpose.  I.e., for some Latin squares $L$, you can permute the symbols of $L^T$ to obtain $L$.  We can identify symbols to obtain the desired frequency squares.

To my knowledge, the only paper that talks about such Latin squares is: Mendis and Wanless, [Autoparatopisms of Quasigroups and Latin Squares](https://doi.org/10.1002/jcd.21515), J. Combin. Des., 2016.  (There may be others that I'm unaware of.)  Theorem 4.7 in this paper gives necessary and sufficient conditions for the existence of these Latin squares.

Comment: It seems like a relaxed version of what I have in mind; I'm going to rewrite this question to be clearer now that some people have responded and just go ahead and give away why I am asking (it's equivalent to an Erdos problem).  It is a relaxed version because just getting the frequency of each color/number is not enough, we will have a particular pattern within the array.

Comment: Maybe it would be best to give an example of a matrix you're referring to?